# spring internationalization in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, internationalization

how to implement i18n support in javascript. I have been through many forums and stackoverflows. but i could not make it work. 
In my case,

I have two Message resources as "message_en.properties" and "message_fr.properties" stored in "src/resources/message" folder
I had used jquery.i18n.properties-min.js but i see no change.

i have defined my "messageResourceBundle" bean with basename as "classpath:message/message" property.

please tell me how to do it or provide me with links of concrete examples for i18n in js with any jquery-plugins available that uses ".properties" file.